# while loop and substring() causing StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I'm trying to replace non-alpanumeric chars only from the beginning of a String. I came up with the following code:

```
public static final class FixNonAlphaNumBegin implements PhraseFilter {
    @Override
    public String filter(String phrase, long frequency) {
        int count = 0;

    while (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(phrase.codePointAt(count))
                && phrase.length() > count + 1) {
            phrase = phrase.replaceFirst(
                    Pattern.quote(phrase.substring(count, count + 1)), "");
            count++;
        }


        return phrase.trim();           
    }
}
```

Where are the IndexOutOfBoundsException is coming from? It should not be possible:

e.g.

```
String filter = "! " 

!Character.isLettorDigit(phrase.codePointAt(0) --> true 
phrase.length() > 1 --> true

phrase = phrase.replaceFirst(
                Pattern.quote(phrase.substring(0, 0 + 1)), "");
```

`phrase` is now `" "` , `count` 1

```
!Character.isLettorDigit(phrase.codePointAt(1) --> true 
phrase.length() > 2 --> false
```

So the loop should break before the exception can happen.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swap your `while` conditions

```
while (count < pharse.length() && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(phrase.codePointAt(count))) {
```

This will cause Java to check that the `count` is less then the length of the `phrase` (remember, it's 0 indexed) first before trying to extract the character from it